# search for the next prime number more efficiently?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation, primes

```
   bool isPrime(int n) const {
    if(n<2)return false;
    if(n==2)return true;
    if(n%2==0)return false;
    for(int i=3;(i*i)<=n;i++){
        if(n%i==0)return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this worst case procedure should produce an O (sqrt (N)) which would be the number of comparisons I am going to do in the for loop.

Now if I add this:

```
    int getPrime(int n) {
    int i=n;
    while(!isPrime(i))
        i++;

    return i;
}
```

I should have an O (n) * O (sqrt (n)) and therefore the total complexity should be O (n ^ 2) more precisely
n for the while loop and n ^ 1/2 the for loop
now if i sum the exponent i will have n ^ 3/5 then
O (n ^ 1.5)

It's right?

does anyone know a way to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to be called a small number of times, efficiency doesn't really matter.

If it's going to be called many times, then `isPrime()` should cache a list of already discovered primes (or an array of booleans indexed by the number to be tested) and run the loop only if *n* is larger than the largest in the list.

If you have some idea of the range of values this is going to be used with, you can seed the cache using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Also, you can trivially cut the time in half by incrementing the loop indices by 2 rather than by 1, skipping the even values.

Comment: I don't think I can use the Sieve of Eratosthenes because I have to find the next prime of any number so I don't know the range of values.
I insert the control number if it is prime if it is not prime then I call isPrime which calculates it for me.
say that the i in the while should be increased by 2?